# Не открывается ссылка

Tags: php

Есть сайт `avito.ru`, если зайти на какое-нибудь объявление то там номера телефона сразу не увидишь, надо нажимать на кнопку "показать телефон", тогда загружается картинка с номером человека который опубликовал само объявление, если проинспектировать эту картинку то там в `src` будет например следующее:

```
/items/phone/moskva_avtomobili_s_probegom_volvo_c30_2008_313304288?pkey=9e7c577a7e9dbf719ab68a798cf7a8bd
```

Но если открыть в новой вкладке:

```
http://www.avito.ru/items/phone/moskva_avtomobili_s_probegom_volvo_c30_2008_313304288?pkey=9e7c577a7e9dbf719ab68a798cf7a8bd
```

то за место картинки с номером будет "ошибка. перезагрузите страницу", вообщем ссылки на номера использовать бесполезно, как они это сделали? можно ли это обойти?

Comment: Они, скорей всего, просто запретили доступ к этим картинкам не со своего хоста. Это легко делается и также легко, бородатыми мужиками каким нечего делать (это я зашутил на ночь глядя))) ), обходится.

Comment: Случай действительно интересный, т.к. не помогает ни передача реферера, ни куки, ни хост...

Comment: Интересовался я этой темой. Делал сборщик данных по объявлениям, когда искал квартиру в аренду. При клике по "Показать телефон" там выводится картинка не с URL'ом в src, а прямо в src сама картинка лежит, закодированная в base64. Оттуда можно выцепить строку и раскодировать. Я использовал Selenium, чтобы ходить по ссылкам и кликать на "Показать телефон", потом получал картинку, раскодировал и распознавал.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Упрощенный метод:

Этот номер является картинкой которая генерируется на лету.
При загрузке страницы давать этой странице рандомный приватный ключ.

Поясню:

При запросе страницы сервер генерирует случайное число и заносит его + телефон продавца в таблицу в бд.

Так же создает переменную JS с этим ключом на самой странице. Итого: на клиенте есть переменная с этим числом и в БД.

Когда нажимаем показать, то мы этот ключ отсылаем на сервер во время запроса изображения:

...?pkey=9e7c577a7e9dbf719ab68a798cf7a8bd - Это и есть приватный ключ

скрипт php дедает так:

Если есть ключ в GET запросе то проверить есть ли этот ключ в бд. 
Если есть, то получаем номер телефона, который относится к этому ключу=>Генерируем изображение=>удаляем из базы этот ключ

Когда вы попытаетесь еще раз запросить это изображение, то этого ключа больше не будет в БД. и вас отправляет на страницу ошибки.

Как обойти? Даже если вы найдете как добыть этот ключ, то это всего лишь на один раз добыть изображение. Скорее всего этот ключ спрятан по кускам. Часть в куках, часть еще где то. а так все что отсылается с клиента все можно подделать. Но как я вам сказал, это изображение показывается всего один раз

---

Разобрался (по понятным причинам я не могу выложить их код):
В данном случае работает так же, как я и описал!
В документе есть такой вот код.(привожу не дословно)

phone = 'ac217d39b22a7e312acd72a1b6b3effc4' ;

С помощью js запрашивается js библиотека с сервера с функцией обработки этого ключа. (Поэтому вы и не можете найти эти функции при просмотре кода). С помощью не хитрых функций мы из этого хэша (phone) получаем новый хэш. Т.е. он изначально phone  - это заготовка хэша, который преобразуется функцией в нужный вид. А дальше получаем изображение. 
Вот и вся наука.

Comment: ключ нигде по кускам не спрятан, он задается на странице объявления
вот так

    <script>
    
    var item_url = 'sharya_avtomobili_s_probegom_vaz_2114_samara_2007_329266948'
    , item_phone = '926e049a7427af4fcd17b1d6c1f9f106d9b79dcf4fc7277a640e62b864bae3c90443789d892wb736403c38ab868w629bd9';
    </script>


потом там для вычисления pkey существует функция phoneDemixer(key) , ничего особенного она не делает, все это подставляется сюда 

    link = '/items/phone/' + item.url + '?pkey=' + phoneDemixer(phoneKey);

никакой магии там вроде нет.

Comment: "Разобрался (по понятным причинам я не могу выложить их код): В данном случае работает так же, как я и описал! В документе есть такой вот код.(привожу не дословно)

phone = 'ac217d39b22a7e312acd72a1b6b3effc4' ;

С помощью js запрашивается js библиотека с сервера с функцией обработки этого ключа. (Поэтому вы и не можете найти эти функции при просмотре кода). С помощью не хитрых функций мы из этого хэша (phone) получаем новый хэш. Т.е. он изначально phone - это заготовка хэша, который преобразуется функцией в нужный вид. А дальше получаем изображение. Вот и вся наука."

Comment: > Скорее всего этот ключ спрятан по кускам

это не так, никуда он не спрятан.

Comment: Я же проапдэтил ответ и под пунктирной линией написал принцип работы. "В документе есть такой вот код.(привожу не дословно)

phone = 'ac217d39b22a7e312acd72a1b6b3effc4' ;" phone - это и есть item_phone

Comment: @Victor Halauko так а зачем вы намеренно всё запутываете ?

Comment: В вопросе не было таких слов: Напишите код, который на этом сайте....
Вопрос был: как они это сделали? можно ли это обойти?

Comment: ну почему не сказать нормальное название переменных ? ну и мой коммент для того чтобы дополнить ваш ответ, отдельным ответом я делать не стал.

Comment: Я объяснил принцип работы, работоспособность которого не зависит от название переменной ) Ладно, не будем ерундой заниматься. Главное, что проблема решена)